# localStorage not working properly on glitch.com?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I created an incremental game, and was interested in storing the variable in localStorage. I decided it would be smart to try it on a small scale first. I read my fair share of w3 tutorials and stack overflow questions, but I couldn't get it to work. I wrote the following:

```
var val; //declares test variable
function incr() {
  val += 1;
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = val; //update the div where the variable is displayed
  console.log(val)
} //called on by an html button
function save() {
  var saveGame = {
    val: val
  }
  localStorage.setItem("saveGame",JSON.stringify(saveGame));
}
setInterval(function() {
  save();
  console.log("Game Saved.")
}, 100)
function saveDataTest() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("saveGame") || null) {
    load();
  } //called on by 'onload' event

}
function load() {
  var loadGame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("saveGame"));
  val = loadGame.val;
} //split string into an object/variable and use said object/variable to define variable
 if (val == undefined){val = 0;}
```

As I mentioned in the title, I am using Glitch.com and considering I can't find anything wrong on my end I thought it might be the website's fault. Please, correct me if I made a mistake in my code.

Comment: if localStorage.getItem("saveGame") has no value then loadGame would be null, you cant access loadGame.val then

Answer (score 0):

```
var val = 0; //declares test variable
function incr() {
  val += 1;
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = val; //update the div where the variable is displayed
  console.log(val)
} //called on by an html button
function save() {
  var saveGame = {
    val: val.toString(),
  }
  localStorage.setItem("saveGame",JSON.stringify(saveGame));
}
window.onload = function() {
  loadGame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("saveGame"));
  load();
};
setTimeout(function() {setInterval(function() {
  save();
  console.log("Game Saved.")
}, 10)},400) //use delay so that game does not save immediately after loading

}
function load() {
if (!(localStorage.getItem("saveGame") == null)) {
  val = Number(loadGame.val);}
} //split string into an object/variable and use said object/variable to define variable
```

Use Number() and .toString() to convert from string to number and vice versa.